# how to calculated the age on birthday date for shamsi calendar with WPF in GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

I have a grid view in wpf(C#) which contain Birth Day Date. I used bellow code for calculated the age for first row. 
Now how to calculated the all row (ages)?

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string birth_day = "";

    var query = from u in db.tbl_User select u;
    var result = query.ToList();
    if (result.Count > 0)
    {
        birth_day = result[0].BirthDayDate;
        DateTime birthdaydate = DateTime.Parse(ShamsiToMiladi(birth_day));
        DateTime todaydate = DateTime.Parse(ShamsiToMiladi(PublicVariable.TodayDate));
        int days = todaydate.Day - birthdaydate.Day;
        if (days < 0)
        {
            todaydate = todaydate.AddMonths(-1);
            days += DateTime.DaysInMonth(todaydate.Year, todaydate.Month);
        }
        int months = todaydate.Month - birthdaydate.Month;
        if (months < 0)
        {
            todaydate = todaydate.AddYears(-1);
            months += 12;
        }
        int years = todaydate.Year - birthdaydate.Year;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} year{1}, {2} month{3} and {4} day{5}",
        years, (years == 1) ? "" : "s",
        months, (months == 1) ? "" : "s",
        days, (days == 1) ? "" : "s"));
}
```

Comment: What are "all ages"? What is the expected output of your code? Why don't you iterate over all rows?

Comment: @NicoHaase thank you. How to iterate over all rows? I think should used foreach but i dont know. All ages means all rows and the all cells contain birthday date. Read birthday at database and calc to age.

Comment: Ok, then go forward with iterating. `foreach` sounds good

Comment: @NicoHaase i dont work with foreach in wpf. Can you help me and modified them? Thank you so much. Excuseme! My language is not good.

Comment: It's no shame to not know how to use a loop yet, but there are tons of tutorials about that, and I don't know that much about C# to help you find the proper syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var query = db.tbl_User.ToList();

    if (!query.Any())return;

    var results = new List<string>();
    foreach(var user in query){
        var birth_day = user.BirthDayDate;
        DateTime birthdaydate = DateTime.Parse(ShamsiToMiladi(birth_day));
        DateTime todaydate = DateTime.Parse(ShamsiToMiladi(PublicVariable.TodayDate));
        int days = todaydate.Day - birthdaydate.Day;
        if (days < 0)
        {
            todaydate = todaydate.AddMonths(-1);
            days += DateTime.DaysInMonth(todaydate.Year, todaydate.Month);
        }
        int months = todaydate.Month - birthdaydate.Month;
        if (months < 0)
        {
            todaydate = todaydate.AddYears(-1);
            months += 12;
        }
        int years = todaydate.Year - birthdaydate.Year;
        results.Add(
            string.Format(
                "{0} year{1}, {2} month{3} and {4} day{5}",
                years, (years == 1) ? "" : "s",
                months, (months == 1) ? "" : "s",
                days, (days == 1) ? "" : "s"
            )
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment but to use *foreach*:

```
if (result.Count > 0)
{
    birth_day = result[0].BirthDayDate;
```

becomes

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    // Use result.BirthDayDate
```